# SQL: Employee and Customer are Users, But not all Employees are Users

Tags: sql, database, database-design, user-roles, domain-model

I'm trying to model a database for a rest server which is accessed via mobile app  and web clients. Both Employees and Customers are users of the system. I have previously used composition rather than inheritance to design the database. I have used the design from this [answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/31198) as such.

- `User` (user_id, fullname, email, username)
- `Role` (role_id, description)
- `UserRole` (user_role_id, user_id,role_id, date_from, date_thru)
- `Customer` (user_id, ...)
- `Employee` (user_id, ...)

The problem is that to have an employee you need to have a user but not all employees are users i.e. I'm currently told to include drivers who are employees but not users of th system. So how can I create such a relationship?

Comment: Have a Person which can be User/ Customer/ Employee

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have another composition level saying called "Person". So employees and customers are persons and persons could be users.

Comment: Let me try and see...but the join will be longer now

Comment: I have used this method

Answer (score 1):

For the employees who are not user, you can have user_id equal to NULL.

Comment: But the user table holds all the common attributes like fullname, email, etc